# awstats для nginx + wordpress: не работает редирект

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect

Пытаюсь настроить awstats для nginx, и это почти удалось: в /var/lib/awstats/ таки создаётся текствый файлик, в который пишется статистика, но все попытки открыть awstats кончаются ошибкой 404 на сайте.

Настройки nginx выглядят так:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root  /usr/share/wordpress;
    location /awstats/ {
        root   /usr/lib/cgi-bin;
        index  index.html index.htm index.pl;
    }
    location /awstatsclasses/ {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/lib/;
    }
    location /awstats-icon/ {
        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/;
    }
    location /awstatscss {
        alias /usr/share/doc/awstats/examples/css/;
    }
}
```

Вообще все настройки взяты отсюда: http://www.tech-notes.net/awstats-for-nginx/

Не могу понять, как это исправить,или хотя бы где можно почитать подробно про настройки nginx для wordpress?

Comment: Настройки nginx для WordPress описаны в Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо, это то, что нужно.